# Registered domain with AWS Route 53 now routes to ghandi.net?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I registered a new domain in `.news` TLD (`example.news`) with Route53. I created a corresponding S3 public bucket (`www.example.news`) with a single `index.html` that says `hello world`. I made the necessary changes to make the S3 bucket public and I can open the public address of the S3 bucket (h`ttp://www.example.news.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`) from my browser and see `hello world`.

In Route53, I created 2 alias records (`example.news`, `www.example.news`) and pointed them to my S3 bucket. I waited 1-2 minutes and loaded the domain in my browser and see `hello world` load as expected. I made no other changes, but I refreshed the browser a few minutes later and now my domain routes to Gandi with a default page with marked up text:

> This domain name has been registered with Gandi.net
>
> View the WHOIS data for example.news to see the domain’s public
>   registration information.

Also, `example.news` changes automatically to `www.example.news`, which seems to suggest my alias records are working.

Why is my domain routing to Gandi when I registered it with Route53? Is there an issue with my nameservers perhaps? What do you recommend to trace down this issue?

edit:
Here is a screenshot of what I see (used inspect to change the domain to example.news):

[image]

Comment: With DNS questions you really need to tell us the domain name if you want useful advice.

Comment: It’s impossible to tell what’s wrong if you don’t tell us the actual domain name. It’s a public domain, there is no point trying to hide it.

Comment: Gandi (no h) is the registrar used behind the scenes if you register domain names through Route53, so the connection there is not particularly mysterious. As for why you get a landing page, I think we'll need more details.

Comment: Give it a few hours and let's see if this resolves itself. It should.  I've seen this with Route 53 -- I don't know whether it's on the AWS side or the Gandi side, but there is an occasional quirk that pops up during name registration that results in the Gandi generic name servers being pushed out to the top-level servers for a time.  As @HåkanLindqvist points out, Gandi handles registrations in some top level domains on behalf of Route 53 Domains.  The only surprising/troubling thing is that it apparently worked as intended for a short time, earlier.  That's a little unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase a domain through AWS-Route 53, a host zone is automatically added with that domain name.(By default, NS and SOA record sets are registered.)

Also register a record set of type A-IPv4.
In "Value", enter the IPv4 of the instance you are using.

Check your domain name server under "Registered Domains".
It must be the same as the name server listed in the NS of the host zone.

Once you're all set up,
**Wait for a while and clear all browser cache.**
Then connect and verify your domain.